# morphisms of projective varieties and induced ring homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of affine varieties, then we get an induced homomorphism $\tilde{\phi} : A(Y) \rightarrow A(X)$ of their affine coordinate rings (and vice versa).

**Question 1:** What is the reason that this nice property does not hold for projective varieties?

**Question 2:** What is the next best thing that is true in general for projective varieties, in terms of a morphism of projective varieties inducing
a homomorphism on their homogeneous coordinate rings?

Comment: To answer your second question, I'd recommend looking at rational maps and the fields of functions.  These have the same kind of correspondence as affine varieties and their coordinate rings.

Comment: As for your first question, the problem is that the complete invariant for affine varieties is the ring of regular functions, which "happens" to be isomorphic to the coordinate ring when your variety is an affine Zariski closed set. So, your morphism actually induces a homomorphism between the algebras of regular functions.

Problem is, though, that regular functions over any closed projective Zariski set are constant, hence not isomorphic to its coordinate ring. And far from being a complete regular-isomorphism invariant.

Comment: @Hayden: I am familiar with the basics of rational maps. I suppose i am trying to put all notions into place. I am curious as to whether the rational maps were developed to circumvent this difficulty associated with projective varieties.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Interesting...and what is the "complete invariant" for projective varieties?

Answer (score 1):

On Question 1 : Definitely there is an induced homomorphism; it is the identity map as both $A(Y)$ and $A(X)$ are the same as the base field.

For Question2: If you want you can consider the induced maps on the affine cones: that is,instead of  regarding the homogeneous ideals as defining  a projective variety in $\mathbf{P}^n$ think of them  as defining an affine variety embedded in $\mathbf{A}^{n+1}$, (of course the maps preserving lines)

The concept  of line bundles on projective varieties is the right one for this.

Comment: I will think about your answer to Question 2. But regarding your answer to my Q1, i am asking about the homogeneous coordinate rings, not the rings of regular functions.